# Flutter TextInputFormatter does not do what is intended

Tags: dart, flutter

I have tried to extend the Flutter's `TextInputFormatter` to add thousand comma separator on the fly as the user types.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';


class ThousandSeparatorTextInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue,
      TextEditingValue newValue) {

    return newValue.copyWith(
      text: _addThousandsSeparator(newValue.text)
    );
  }

  // This adds thousand comma separator
  String _addThousandsSeparator(String value) {
    RegExp reg = RegExp(r'(\d{1,3})(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))');
    Function determine = (Match match) => '${match[1]},';
    return value.replaceAllMapped(reg, determine);
  }
}
```

The problem is when used in the `TextField` the comma separator appears at the right position the first time, as the user keep typing the separator appears after every digit from the last three.

When the _addThousandSeparator function is used on its own, i.e. on some values, it does work. What am I doing wrong?